# animated chart control for asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, graph, system.diagnostics

I am trying to write an application that will reflect and update some statistics info of performance while a task is running (a benchmark app)

the issue is, that it's related to systems info, Such as CPU usage and memory allocation 
so i need to reflect those calculations and make a **simple way** to update that graph with the new numbers translated visually ( with any user /programmer custom interval of update frequency) or even calculated based on overall system resources so if the system is not too busy 
frequency will be max speed...

the question is , what to start with ?

using a progress bar of Winforms was my first thought (thinking simple as less as i could use lines of code for that specific task of displaying the data )

i am using `c# .net 4.0 ASP Webforms` .
can you please guide me to a simple way, how to implement this?

could be in C# asp.net or mixed with javascript /jQuery

PS

i was thinking of an approach, to have multiple images : 
from an empty-bar  till full-bar (switch between them according to calculation) , though i need a faster response than replacing `src` of  `img`.
maybe a pixel wise action, ... a `div`s with bgcolor... height will change so it's kind of a bar meter... really I could think of many ways to try implementing the task at hand,
though i thought there is a known way (keeping simple in mind).

just for illustration , this is 2 options(vertical or horizontal ) i thought of how to display statistics visually .

i don't mind which of [those graphs(LINK)](http://www.rcl.co.il/images/SOG/GCSraph.png) as long as the implementation will be as simple as it could be 
and response will be fast to make it happen without being heavy task .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would consider [FusionCharts](http://www.fusioncharts.com/) They have a nice assortment of chart types, very nice visual, and very simple implementation. You can supply data directly in XML or JSON format, either from server-side or directly to the client, so [real-time updates](http://www.fusioncharts.com/demos/features/#self-updating-charts) are supported as well.

Oh and even though this is a commercial product, they do have a free version.